# Exiting from golang gracefully in Windows on terminal

Tags: windows, go, operating-system

I have trouble exiting gracefully from my own go program on Windows. os.Interrupt doesn't seem to work either. I am wondering if there is any way to exit golang program gracefully in a terminal?

```golang
func main() {

    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)

    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println(sig)
        done <- true
    }()

    fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}
```

Comment: I'd quess you have to (also) listen for `os.Interrupt`, ie add it into the `signal.Notify` list.

Comment: Define "gracefully"? What specifically about the behavior do you want to change?

Comment: Considering Windows doesn't have any real implementation of POSIX signals at the kernel level, it's pretty opaque what golang does for `SIGTERM`. Usually language runtimes map `SIGINT` to the Windows console's `CTRL_C_EVENT`, if it's a console application. So a user can exit gracefully, if handled, via Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working fine, the program exited gracefully, I tested it on windows command prompt.

To convince you even more, try to add `time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)` after `<-done`, then test. When you interrupt it, program will only be closed after 5 seconds passed.

```golang
fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
<-done

fmt.Println("exiting in 5 seconds")
time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
fmt.Println("exit success")
```

Also like @ain said on comment, try to add `os.Interrupt` on `signal.Notify`

```golang
signal.Notify(sigs, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: It doesn't work on Windows 10 : CTRL+C works (program is closed after 10 seconds), program is closed after 6 seconds when click on the window cross, Windows can't be shutdow (it stays busy).
https://go.dev/play/p/mGo_PKpA4nw